# Creating circular time range selection using HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

For one of my application i am creating circular time range selector widget.I   have created the clock dial using html canvas.I need help to select time range by touch and drag on the dial as shown in the image[Circular clock dial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4maG.jpg). When clicked on the "Add" button, the previous selection should be cleared. Next time i should be able to set new range. this continues. The range value should be stored in a variable. It should work on the mobile device. Your help would be appreciated. http://codepen.io/harish_s/pen/ggpoBq

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.translate(radius, radius);
    radius = 180;
    drawClock();

    function drawClock() {
      drawFace(ctx, radius);
      drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
    }

    function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
      var grad;
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(207,207,207)";
      ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
      ctx.lineWidth = 60;
      ctx.stroke();
      
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, 150, 0, 2*Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(243,244,244)";
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.font = '25pt Calibri';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.fillText('SET', -25, 10);
    }

    function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
      var ang;
      var num;
      ctx.font = radius*0.20 + "px arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
      ctx.textBaseline="middle";
      ctx.textAlign="center";
      for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
        ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, -radius*1);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
        ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, radius*1);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
    }
    }
```

```css
#canvas{
 position: absolute;
 width: 50%;
 left: 35%;
  top:5%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500">
</canvas>
```

Comment: You can not really expect someone will program all the functionality of this widget for you. That is not the purpose of stackoverflow, it's not a code writing service. Perhaps this [example on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9020206/1456318) can give you some ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular range selection control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017536/circular-range-selection-control)